# Get From-To Fields in hierarchical format from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have MySQL table as below. In which have 2 fields. **From** and **To**. (and my code is in PHP).

```
Id    |From    |To
------|--------|--------
1     |1       |2
2     |2       |4
3     |3       |4
4     |4       |5
5     |4       |6
6     |5       |7
7     |6       |8
8     |8       |9
```

Now to get Graph kind thing as HTML output, Is there any way to give representation like I am expecting in as few as possible MySQL query?

```
1 ----- 2     5 ----- 7
         \   /
          \ /
           4
          / \
         /   \
        3     6 ----- 8 ----- 9
```

What I am doing now is, If I search Graph for "**4**", first I will get all backward points and then move ahead to get all forward points.

Comment: can you add sample exmaple for expected output ?

Comment: Currently I am getting 1-D Array in PHP. But want some output like 2-D array, so we can visualize directly from that Array.

Comment: You need only one query for building that graph: take all transitions at once, because you'll need them anyway, and then build the graph using an available library. It *should be* more efficient than accessing the database *N* times.

Comment: As you've discovered, mysql has no support for recursion 'out-of-the-box'. Options include writing a sproc, joining the table to itself as often as could be required, switching to an alternative model (i.e. nested set), or handling the recursion logic in your application code (PHP).